# Google Analytics after Clear Data or Clear Cache

Tags: android, google-analytics

If I clear the data or cache of my app, will this affect the Google analytics events yet to dispatch?

Based on Google Analytics documentation, the GA hits are stored locally and dispatched to server in a particular interval (local dispatch period). If I clear the data of my app, will this clear the locally stored google analytics hits?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Data collected using the **[Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/)** SDK v4 for Android is stored locally before being dispatched on a separate thread to Google Analytics.

> If a user loses network access or quits your app while there are still
>   hits waiting to be dispatched, those hits are persisted in local
>   storage. They will be dispatched the next time your app is running and
>   dispatch is called.

Read official guideline about [**`Dispatching`**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch) .

Comment: Hi IntelliJ Amiya, Thanks for your answer! My question was, if I clear the data of my app from "Settings => Application Manager", will this clear the persisted hits in local storage?

Comment: @coder Maybe. Example, If your LOCAL DB path set to Custom folder and then `CLEAR DATA` It will not effect but If LOCAL DB path set to `INBUILT` location then it will be clear .